# Problem with @awesome-cordova-plugins/barcode-scanner/ngx library on Ionic 7.1.1: Error in starter-barcodescanner.gradle

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

am facing a problem when trying to use the @awesome-cordova-plugins/barcode-scanner/ngx library in an Ionic 7.1.1 project with Cordova 12.0.0. When I build the project for the Android platform, I get the following error:

```
/platforms/android/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/starter-barcodescanner.gradle' line: 9[cordova][cordova] * What went wrong:[cordova] A problem occurred evaluating script.[cordova] > Could not find method compile() for arguments [{name=barcodescanner-release-2.1.5, ext=aar}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I have checked the versions of my dependencies and they are as follows:

```
Ionic: 7.1.1
Cordova: 12.0.0 (cordova-lib@12.0.1)
Node.js: v16.20.2
```